# Reading the run mode in Yesod

Tags: testing, yesod

How can I determine the run mode (`Development`, `Testing`, `Staging`, `Production`) in a Yesod application?

I have a service that should return a value only in `Development` and `Testing` modes. The value is a secret token that will be sent as part of a validation for a newly registered user.

In `Development` and `Testing` modes I need to verify that the token sent is the same as the token generated.

In a previous version of Yesod (1.2, I believe), I used the following code, but it no longer compiles:

```
case appEnv $ settings $ getYesod of
    Development -> -- value to return in Development
    Testing -> -- value to return in Testing
    _ -> -- value to return in Staging and Production
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the newest versions of the scaffolding, we no longer have the concept of environments. Command line arguments can be used to switch which config files we read from, but that's it. If you'd like access to that information, you could use `getArgs`.